# Symbology Representations in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, representation

Is there a way to create and apply non-destructive symbology to features in QGIS?

In ArcGIS, you can create 'representations' of a feature classes symbology, which allows you to make independent adjustments to appearance, position or visibility, without affecting the underlying data.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what exactly you would like to accomplish. I find it hard to see how appearance and visibility could change the underlying data (while I see how positional changes may be achieved by adjusting the data).

Comment: He means moving the symbol for a feature to a move appropriate place (one that the symbol renderer doesn't pick itself), and/or manually overriding the symbology the renderer picks - and storing the change in the table ... QGIS doesn't appear to have that ability for symbols (you can accomplish what 'geodatabase annotation' does using X,Y, Rotation, Size fields in the table and tools in QGIS to move the labels)

Comment: I still can't follow based on which parameters the adjustments should happen and "storing the change in the table" sounds destructive to me. I guess I am still missing a point. But I could imagine that [geometry generators](http://www.opengis.ch/2015/12/10/geometry-generator-symbology/) (available in QGIS 2.14) could be something in this direction.

Comment: Or is it related to the proposal for [auxiliary storage](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/27).

Comment: Hi. I've not had a chance to come back regarding the comments until now. Basically, 'mapBaker' has got what I am after. I want to be able to manually shift symbols to a better position than where the data actually plots them, to avoid clashes with other map elements. I have had a quick look at the geometry generators page and that looks like it may be what I am looking for. I will test this and let you know.